# MEAN-stack binding from Angular does not work

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have in login.component.ts:

```
type: String;
typesOfUsers = [{ name: 'kupac' }, { name: 'admin' }];
```

And in login.component.html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="type">
       <option *ngFor="let t of typesOfUsers" [ngValue]="t.name">
            {{t.name}}
       </option>
</select>
```

However when I log this argument (type) on the backend, I get - undefined.

I tried to bind statically but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I just added name property in select component of HTML and it works:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="type" name="type">
       <option *ngFor="let t of typesOfUsers" [ngValue]="t.name">
              {{t.name}}
       </option>
</select>
```